# Hi Small help, can any one suggest me on this

Tags: lightning-web-components

How to display Owner name instead of owner Id in Lightning data table in LWC.

```
Oppcolumns = [
    {
        label: "Name", type: "button",
        typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: "Name" }, name: "goto", variant: "base" }
        
    },
    {
        label: 'Opportunity Owner', fieldName: 'Owner.name', type: 'text',
    },
```

Comment: You can change the data either in back end and create a wrapper and send the data to UI. Or in UI layer manipulate the data to extract name if its already there with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use relationships as value. Your data structure should be plain.

The easiest way to do something like that is:

```js
this.opportunities = data.map(opportunity => ({
    ...opportunity,
    OwnerName: opportunity.Owner.name
}));
```

and use in you columns `OwnerName` instead of `Owner.name`.

```js
{
   label: 'Opportunity Owner', fieldName: 'OwnerName', type: 'text'
},
```

Comment: Thank You for your help